How to avoid Access violation executing location when calling C function from managed .NET code?
I have a following code in C++:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport)
        void addInArray(int** c, int* a, int* b, int size)
        {
            *c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                (*c)[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            }
        }
}

int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    int* a = new int[size];
    int* b = new int[size];
    int* c;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
        b[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    addInArray(&c, a, b, size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d = %d + %d\n", c[i], a[i], b[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
}

When I ran this as a separate application it works all right.
However, when I try to run it from the following (roughly simmilar) .NET code
[DllImport($"ArrayCreation.exe")]
public static extern int addInArray(out int[] c, int[] a, int[] b, int size);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int size = 10;
    int[] c;
    int[] a = new int[size];
    int[] b = new int[size];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = random.Next(100);
        b[i] = random.Next(100);
    }
    addInArray(out c, a, b, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{c[i]} = {a[i]} + {b[i]}");
    }
}

I get the "Access violation executing location" error when calling malloc in addInArray function.
Please help me to get this right.
//UPDATE
The effects are exactly the same regardless of the fact if I set CallingConvention to Cdecl
[DllImport("ArrayCreation.exe", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

or StdCall
[DllImport("ArrayCreation.exe", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]


Your code is not C, which does not have the new keyword.

@WeatherVane It is. The code he asks about. Other code does not matter

@gulpr it says "I have a following code in C" and both codes use new. It might have compiled, but not with a C compiler.

@WeatherVane Yes, I have used C++ compiler and used new keyword. However, it does not change the fact that C/C++ code works as intended (memory is allocated, addition is performed), while when calling the same thing from managed dotnet code I cannot allocate the memory and get the error.
EDIT
I have changed the new to malloc for you convenience

@WeatherVane The second code is written in C# and build as .NET Core 8.0 application

Reverting to the original code, not an ad hoc edit, why are you allocating memory for a and b with new and then calling free() to release them?

The main function in C was written just to test if addInArray function works. My problem is how to make it right for .NET Core integration

Yeah, your C++ code can't create an int[] so that can't fly

As David Heffernan has already pointed out, I don't think .NET's int[] (Managed Memory) can receive Unmanaged Memory allocated through Native C++ processing.
If you want to allocate memory in Native C++, like in your current code, you can use IntPtr to receive it. However, in this case, the received memory must be freed using Native C++.

        void addInArray(int** c, int* a, int* b, int size)
        {
            *c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                (*c)[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            }
        }

        void FreeMemory(int* c){
            free(c);
        }

[DllImport($"ArrayCreation.exe")]
public static extern int addInArray(out IntPtr c, int[] a, int[] b, int size);

[DllImport($"ArrayCreation.exe")]
public static extern void FreeMemory(IntPtr c);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
//Omit
    addInArray(out var buf, a, b, size);
    c = new int[size];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(buf, c, 0, size);
    FreeMemory(buf);
//Omit
}


Since the caller seems to have knowledge of the required size, .NET can also allocate memory. In that case, the code would look like this:

        void addInArray(int* c, int* a, int* b, int size)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            }
        }

[DllImport($"ArrayCreation.exe")]
public static extern int addInArray(IntPtr c, int[] a, int[] b, int size);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
//Omit
    var buf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size * sizeof(int));
    addInArray(buf, a, b, size);
    c = new int[size];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(buf, c, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buf);
//Omit
}


These codes were written without a compiler. I think there are a number of small mistakes, but I hope that I can convey what I want to do.

Probably an error in the calling convention for the addInArray function.
Because nothing is specified in the C++ code, the VC++ addInArray function has a calling convention of cdecl.
DllImport in .NET, however, defaults to calling in StdCall on Windows. I believe this is why there is a stack mismatch and illegal memory access is occurring.
I think the problem can be solved by changing the addInArray in C++ function's  calling convention to __stdcall, or by specifying Cdecl for CallingConvention of DllImport in .NET.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention?view=net-8.0

I have already tried setting calling convention on dotnet side (did not help). I will try changing it on C++ side

Stop trying and guessing. Set the calling convention to match on both ends. Don't try all the calling conventions. Know which one is used, and use that.
